# xpages align a column icon from viewPanel

Tags: xpages

In lotus notes there is a simple way to align a column value / icon:

[image]

Regarding XPages, I tried adding `align:right` into the `<xp:this.iconSrc>` property, but it isn't working.

Is there a chance/a way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to you view column style property

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Thanks, I used just align: center.